# Cross site swf load and play mp3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, audio, flash

I have soundmanager2 as player for mp3 sounds.
When I loading .swf file from same server as webapp its playing mp3 files normally

When I load .swf file from another server its not okay

The only change i added is:

```
  soundManager.setup({
    url: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/swf/'
  })
```

In firebug>Net bookmark i can see that swf loaded but no mp3 load (when i click play in site)

I added crossdomain.xml but this not helped.
Worked according to this sample: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/getstarted/

Assume my webapp running locally at: http://local.dev
and swf served in another localapp running under http://local.media

so when i do:

```
url: 'http://local.media/swf/'
```

from local.dev app, its not loading nor playing.

Answer (score 0):

Even for amazon it has to have crossdomain.xml :-\ even if i managed ACL well